# std::move a non-copyable object into a vector

Tags: c++11

Consider this:

```
struct A{};
struct B
{
    // make object non-copyable
    B ( const B & )                 = delete;
    B & operator= ( const B & )     = delete;

    B(){};
    std::unique_ptr<A> pA;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::vector<B> vb;

    vb.push_back(std::move(b));

    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
../src/Sandbox.cpp:24:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: use of deleted function ‘B::B(const B&)’
```

Who is calling the deleted copy constructor? I am trying to move the object not copy it since it has a unique_ptr member.

---

As suggested by commentators:

I tried to implement a move constructor:

```
B ( const B && rhs_ )
{
    pA = std::move(rhs_.pA); // error below
}
```

and replaced `push_back(std::move(b))` with `emplace_back(std::move(b))`

I got this error

```
../src/Sandbox.cpp:17:25: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = A; _Dp = std::default_delete<A>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<A>]’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emplace_back` will work for that. It calls the most suitable constructor instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this is happening? Also,  emplace_back  gave same error

Comment: @Kam I think your move constructor got deleted too. Try to default it.

Comment: @Kam this is happening because by design push_back calls the copy constructor, while emplace_back passes its parameters to the constructor.

Comment: @Kam move constructor should not take the parameter as const.

Comment: Oups :) it works. Thanks! Would you know why was the move constructor deleted?

Comment: @Kam And you can just default the constructor like the deleted syntax just with = default

Comment: @Kam there are rules when the move constructor is automatically generated. Deleting a constructor makes it not automatically generated.

Comment: @Dani The fact is that you have a *user-declared* copy-constructor (it has nothing to do with it being deleted) that causes the move-constructor to not be implicitly declared. Simply defaulting a move-constructor will work (`B(B&&) = default`).